# What is the point of view nodes in JSF 2.2?

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2, flow-scope

What is the benefit of defining some view as flow view node?

View node can be defined using [`FlowBuilder#viewNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/flow/builder/FlowBuilder.html#viewNode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or using `view` tag in `faces-config.xml` or in separate flow definition file. E.g.

```xml
<view id="page2">
    <vdl-document>/flow1/flow1-page2.xhtml</vdl-document>
</view>
```

I understand that this definition is required for determining the start node. But why define other views as members of flow when

- other views have access to flow scoped beans too,
- navigation from flow view to non-flow view works ok?